# Unattened intallation of Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create an INI file for use in an unattended installation. I'm tried using various combinations of the 'createunattended' switch.

setup /createunattendfile C:\temp\vs2008_install.ini

and

setup /createunattend C:\temp\vs2008_install.ini

This launches the installer. Then, selecting a custom install, the VS installer just continues onto the attended install without creating the INI file. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK got it. The setup executable that needs to be run is under the setup directory, and not the setup executable in the root directory of installation disk.

eg: setup/setup.exe /createunattend C:\temp\vs2008_unattended.ini